# Whats the source of the shadows in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See linked figure. There is a sun (the green square) directly above the robot and scene yet the shadows fall to the bottom right corner.

Whats the source of this shadowing?

[link text](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mfallon/share/2013feb/shadow_issue/shadows.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1521/whats-the-source-of-the-shadows-in-gazebo?/) by [techy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/227/techy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is not currently shown in the GUI is the direction of a directional light: http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.3.html#direction

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0